# Outlook 2010 gmail setup error

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

I installed Outlook 2010 on a new Win 10 machine. It is also on my Win 7 machine. I'm transitioning from Win 7 to Win 10.

I can't connect to gmail. It is the only email account I use. I am using IMAP. I'm certain that my password and email address are correct. I went to manually configure. After I set everything up it fails trying to do a test message. Here are the messages I'm getting.

`Log onto incoming mail server (IMAP): The connection to the server was interrupted. If this problem continues, contact your server administrator or Internet service provider.`

`Send test e-mail message: Your e-mail server rejected your login. Verify your user name and password for this account in Account Settings.`

Before I got these messages I kept getting that annoying password prompt popup.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you log onto GMAIL and [enable IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en)? I'm actually facing this exact issue with my father in law's PC! I have other accounts (GMX, and connections to my personal server) and they work fine! Only GMAIL fails.

Comment: Yes. I can login to gmail through my browser. Both IMAP and POP are enabled.

Comment: Please have a look at the pictures below and check that your settings match that in my pictures. Also even though this is Outlook 2013 the version should not matter.

Comment: Can you try (if in safe environment) to disable the antivirus and firewall? I don't think this will help but it's worth ruling it out (please update your question to state you tried it and the result). Also [update your post](http://superuser.com/posts/1093123/edit) to state you tried another machine and result. Remember this is a Q and A site, so it's fine to edit your original post to keep updating it with relevant info. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if you get one!

Comment: Just to double check the following settings:   Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server: imap.gmail.com
Requires SSL: Yes
Port: 993
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.gmail.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for SSL:: 465 or 587
Use same settings as incoming mail server

Answer (score 2):

I would start by checking that you have the correct IMAP settings and that IMAP is enabled on your GMail account.

Correct IMap Settings:

```
Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server:    imap.gmail.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Port: 993 (SSL)
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server:    smtp.gmail.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Port: 465 (SSL)
```

[image: EMail Settings]

[image: SMTP Auth]

If you're still having connectivity issues try pinging both servers.

```
Windows Key + R
Type CMD then press Enter
ping imap.gmail.com
ping smtp.gmail.com
```

[image: Pinging The Google Mail Servers]

Still Not Working? Let's try using Telnet To Connect To The Google Servers.

**Start By Installing It**

[image: Installing Telnet Client]

Now Open A CMD Window.
And Type

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

You should get a blank CMD window, this is good as the server is awaiting instructions since we don't have any just type something random and it will disconnect.

[image: Blank Telnet Window]

If you don't get the Black Telnet Window then you either have a firewall in place or your isp is blocking you. Check with your router's manufacturer for more information. Also contact your ISP.

If you do get a black window then this means that your computer and GMail's servers are able to communicate. The next thing we can try is downloading thunderbird (a outlook alternative). We will attempt to connect to the gmail servers using this to try to rule out all possibles but Outlook.

Download it from `https://www.ninite.com/thunderbird`then run it Ninite is harmless and will just install thunderbird.

Once it is installed add your account.
[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]
[image: IMG3]
[image: IMG4]

Did you get this prompt? This means that your account does not permit connections by less secure apps such as Outlook.

Now that you have we have finally identified the problem, you may close out of Thunderbird and remove it from your computer if you wish. Now lets go to your google account panel follow this link `https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps`
[image: IMG10]

This is the best explanation of what "less secure apps" are and how google auth works. First of all let me start off by saying that I can not 100% guarantee the accuracy of this information however I don't really think anyone can without working at Google for several years. So let's start off with what a "less secure app" is, it is any app that google can NOT popup a window like the one seen in the second to the bottom image to truly verify you are who you say you are with either, an alternate email, a phone, or the google auth app. Outlook is a really good example it does not allow these popups to exist so therefore is marked as an less secure app. Don't get this confused with an unsecure app which will not work at all with Google as far as I know, these do not communicate over ssl  AT ALL and instead use plain text auth which can easily be copied and stolen. Now how the auth process works (again as far as I know) When a Google gets a request from let's say Outlook 2010 on the IP address of 8.8.8.8 (This would never auctually be the ip it would get but you get the point). Now Google knows that this is a "less secure app" and therefore will deny the request EVEN IF THE EMAIL AND PASS ARE CORRECT. Now let's take Mozilla Thunderbird it connects to Google at that same IP address of 8.8.8.8 now Google knows this app supports its popup auth window and sends Mozilla Thunderbird the request to open the window with a onetime unique url generated by google the user signs in and uses let's say a phone and gets the text puts in the good (which is correct) Google will now check the code is correct, sees that it is correct and accepts the request. Now Note that there is far more involved and that you will be always forced to auth on the web site if your ip is new to google. I hope that this clears it up at least a little, and if someone knows more about this than I do feel free to edit this and make it more detailed and accurate.

**URL FOR LESS SECURE APPS**

`https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps`

Now personally I have had this on for years and never once had a problem but I TAKE NO RESPONSIBILITY IF YOU ACCOUNT IS HACKED BECAUSE OF THIS!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41675/discussion-on-answer-by-charles-ludlow-outlook-2010-gmail-setup-error).

Answer (score 0):

I never could get Outlook to work despite all the wonderful help. I tried Thunderbird, but couldn't get the calendar to work. I am using eM Client instead of Outlook & Thunderbird. It looks & works a lot like Outlook and is free.

Comment: I worked on Outlook some more and finally got the idea that maybe I could make a simple change that would work. Outlook worked with the alternate gmail address so I simply changed the gmail address in that account to my primary gmail address and updated the password. It works! I'm so happy to get Outlook back. eM Client is pretty good, but somewhat different from Outlook.